# JBoss EJB Based Web Services Date Format

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I'm developing a webservice using JBoss. Something like this:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/EJB3/EJBBasedWebServices.htm

In concrete a have a field like this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createAt;
```

It works very well, except a minor/major detail... the formatting of a date field.
When I invoke my webservice, the response is something like:

> 2010-11-23T10:10:10Z

I pretend to have all my dates with the following format:

> 2010-11-23T10:10:10

In debug mode, I noticed that "cdate" in "Date" is 2010-11-23T10:10:10Z so I should have a way to override the cdate to remove the "Z" but I don't know where.

Note that I already tried the DateFormat (it doesn't work) :(

The same happens when I use Timestamp or Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it into a Java Date object by using a pattern that matches the date you have and creating the Date object based on this pattern.

You can use a pattern with [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and get whatever format you like.

Comment: With the pattern i have my Date just like "2010-11-23 10:10:10" but the field in the webservice response is "2010-11-23T10:10:10Z" (the cdate information) and a need to remove the Z

Comment: Do you have a Java Date object that contains a value? If you do, then format this with SimpleDateFormat in the way that you want it. You should not look inside of this object.

Comment: No, it´s something related to http://www.jboss.org/jbossws (some configuration, i believe). The SimpleDateFormat doesn´t work. But thank you anyway.

Comment: See if you can it it into a Java Date object then. Most non-Java date objects have a way to do that.

Comment: I expanded my answer to maybe help you.